# X11 Mouse Movement Event

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, mousemove

When creating a Window in XLib

1. What are the masks I provide to the `SetWindowAttributes.event_mask` member?
2. What do I have to pass to the 11th paramater of `XCreateWindow()`
3. What are the Events I am looking for in the main message loop (Where I use `XNextEvent(lDisplay, &xEvent);`?
4. Since X behaves differently than Microsoft's Win32 API, how do I determine if the mouse is over my window or a window in my "Application" and not over the desktop?

I have looked for a similar post. If there is already one out there please point me in the right direction.

---

**Update**

For those who want the easy answer to parts 1-3:

1.

```
xAttributes.event_mask =  ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | ButtonPress |
                          StructureNotifyMask | ButtonReleaseMask |
                          KeyReleaseMask | EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask |
                          PointerMotionMask | Button1MotionMask | VisibilityChangeMask |
                          ColormapChangeMask;
```

---

2.

`unsigned long valuemask = CWEventMask | CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel | CWCursor;`

---

1. ```
                   switch (xEvent.type)
                   {
                   case MapNotify:
                       break;
                   case Expose:
                       // If this is not the last expose event break
                       if (xEvent.xexpose.count != 0)
                           break;
                       else
                           break;
                   case ConfigureNotify:
                       break;
                   case VisibilityNotify:
                       break;
                   case DestroyNotify:
                       break;
                   case ButtonPress:
                   case ButtonRelease:
                   case EnterNotify:
                   case MotionNotify:
                   case LeaveNotify:
                       if(_mouseHandler)
                           _mouseHandler->HandleInput(lDisplay, &xEvent);
                       break;
                   case KeyPress:
                   case KeyRelease:
                       if(_keyboardHandler)
                           _keyboardHandler->HandleInput(lDisplay, &xEvent);
                       break;
                   default:
                       if(_keyboardHandler)
                           _keyboardHandler->HandleInput(lDisplay, &xEvent);
                       break;
                   }
   ```

Comment: XLib is pretty well documented.  Did you try searching the Internet?  For example [XLib Programming Manual: Event Masks](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/mask.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XLib is pretty well documented.  For example [XLib Programming Manual: Event Masks](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/mask.html)

Comment: Just letting you know - that link is broken now.

Comment: Not anymore, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

The first three are well-documented, I think.

To determine whether the mouse is over your window, listen to Enter and Leave events. The `xev` utility is a great way to understand what events exist in the X window system, and when they are sent.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about `xev`, very useful indeed.